# Помогите сделать функцию редактирования фото

Tags: python, sql, aiogram

сделал функцию изменения фото, ошибок нету (в коде есть проверка через print, новое фото выводитсья в консоль, но в БД не изменяется

Код функции (последний этап):

```
@dp.message_handler(state=photo.photo_it, content_types=types.ContentType.PHOTO)
async def photo_upd(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        photo_it = data['photo_it'] = message.photo[-1].file_id
        model = data['model_photo']
    await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f"Фото было обновлено, для модели {model}")
    print(photo_it)
    await db.edit_photo(photo_it=photo_it, model=model)
    await state.finish()
```

Код БД:

```
async def edit_photo(photo_it: str, model: str):
    cur.execute("UPDATE items SET photo_it = ? WHERE model = ?", (model, photo_it,))
    db.commit()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

не знаю проблема в чём но ты поменял местами `model` и `photo_it`

```
async def edit_photo(photo_it: str, model: str):
    cur.execute("UPDATE items SET photo_it = ? WHERE model = ?", (photo_it, model,))
    db.commit()
```

и ещё я думаю незачем делать sqlite функции асинхронными